# how can i split a string if there is a period and then a space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Right now I am using `.split(/(?<=[.])/)` which splits keeps the period.

```
string = "Going home. See you soon."
```

`=> ["Going home.", "See you soon."]`

But what I need is to split on and keep `". "`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can match space () following `.` (`(?<=\.)`):

```
string = "Going home. See you soon."
string.split(/(?<=\.) /)
=> ["Going home.", "See you soon."]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is that straight forward, why you need a regex, just provide the string to split on as

```
"Going home. See you soon.".split('. ').map{ |s| "#{s}." }
```

Comment: i want to keep the delimiter. that cuts it out.

Comment: => ["going home", "see you soon"]